# Proper way to store user roles in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-mvc, authorization

Working on an ASP.NET Core MVC project which has role-based authorization. There are 5 different roles in my system. Based on the role, any user will have access to different section/operations.

My current implementation looks something like this.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin,Supervisor,SeniorContributor,Contributor,SeniorConsumer,Consumer")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index() 
{
    ..
}

[Authorize(Roles = "Admin,Supervisor,SeniorContributor,Contributor")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int Id) 
{
    ..
}

[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int Id) 
{
    ..
}
```

As you can see I have mentioned the roles as string in authorize attribute. Is this the right way to do or I store it in some enum and use it here or what's the best practice of doing this ?

Comment: You can Make constants for your application and manage your roles in constants variables and access those constants

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a very good question actually. These attribute / annotation based solutions are often advertised by vendors, but they have maintainability, extensibility and client problems, so personally I have always avoided them.

**USE STANDARD PATTERNS**

Put the authorization logic in classes that can adapt to change easily, and that are testable:

- A filter class for rules that applies to all endponits
- A policy class that applies to a subset of endpoints
- Use code within each method if it is specific

These options will also give you better control over error responses returned to clients, and it is important to get this working in a consistent way - eg attribute 403 responses should not use a different error format to other authorization checks.

.Net actually has some good API policy features, as in [this code example](https://github.com/curityio/dotnet-api-jwt-validation/blob/master/Controllers/WeatherForecastController.cs) but I don't know if you can use that in a web back end.

**ROLES AND CLAIMS**

In .Net the role is just one field - and you should ensure that your authorization logic has access to the full ClaimsPrincipal. This will give you best options as authorization rules (and names of roles) change.